# How can I setup a dual SSH tunnel so that two machines A and B behind firewalls ssh into a central sever such that A can VNC into B?

Tags: ssh, firewall, proxy, vnc, tunneling

I need to connect via VNC from my machine A to another machine belonging to my friend B.
Both of us have no way to open incoming ports - ISPs do not allow tunneling unless you buy a static IP based business plan.
Both are linux systems BTW

We have a web server with full access, where we can both ssh into.
How do we setup a tunnel from either end to teh server so that VNC works?

I know how to setup an ssh tunnel between two systems and I believe its not hard to do A->B->C by running ssh first on A to B and then on B to C

But I need A->C and B->C rather than A->B and B->C

Basically I think I need a proxy server - can this be done with SSH or even some sort of linux networking magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say C is the webserver that you both (A: You & B: Your friend) have access to.

#### Setup for C: Add gatewayports yes to the config

vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

add "GatewayPorts yes" at the bottom so the remote host will listen on the 0.0.0.0 interface instead of the 127.0.0.1 interface

GatewayPorts yes

#### Setup for B: Forward localhost's "port2" to remote host's (C) "port1"

ssh -i auth.pem -R 0.0.0.0:port1:localhost:port2 xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx

#### Setup for A: No need for forwarding.

You can now connect to C's port2 using VNC while actually viewing B's screen.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the answer you're looking for, but two services to check out:

- Hamachi (https://vpn.net)
- ZeroTier (https://www.zerotier.com)

They do roughly the same thing. Both allow you to create virtual private networks between multiple computers without needing to do any firewall or port forwarding configuration. Both services have a free tier, although if you need lots of computers connected, ZeroTier allows more computers on their free version. Both work on Linux, Windows and Mac OS (ZeroTier works on a bunch of other platforms too).